# IBM Verse API in C# application

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, ibm-verse

I am creating application to sync with IBM verse. As per [documentaion](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API%20Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Step_2_Obtain_authorization_code_sbt&content=apicontent) I have registered application. In 2nd step I am trying to obtain the authorization code. For this my application should redirect to web-browser but failed to do so. What I am doing wrong? Please suggest.

```
String requrl = "https://apps.na.collabserv.com/manage/oauth2/authorize";
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requrl);

                request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

                request.Headers.Add("response_type", "code");

                request.Headers.Add("client_id", "app_1000233222_1505984966292");

                request.Headers.Add("callback_uri", "https://localhost/callback");

                request.Method = "GET";

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);

                    }


                }
```